# How to update integer values stored in a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python

I have created a simple game in python and I have declared a dictionary `points={'Player1':0, 'Player2':0}` so if Player 1 gets a point I want the value of Player1 in points to be 1.

so I want my final output to be `points={'Player1':1, 'Player2':0}`

I tried using the `points.update()` but I am not getting the desired output.

Comment: *How* did you try `points.update()`, what were you expecting, and what happened instead?

Comment: `points['Player1'] = 1` or `points.update({'Player1': 1})`

Comment: `points['Player1']+=1;`

Comment: Did you read through the documentation for dictionaries to see how they work?  [Here's a link for you.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
Search in your browser for any tutorial on Python dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

To change values in a dictionary, you only need to access its key:

```
points['Player1'] = 1
```

in your case, I think you want

```
points['Player1'] += 1 #increment by one
```

if you wish to iterate over all players:

```
for key in points.keys():
  points[key] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the dictonary like normal, with `myDictonary['key'] = value`

```
Python 3.5.3
>>> points={'P1':0, 'P2':0}
>>> points['P1'] += 1
>>> points
{'P1': 1, 'P2': 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `points` dictionary, you have two keys, `Player1` and `Player2`.

When you use the dictionary `update()` method, you need to specify which key you want to update. To do this, it needs a new dictionary.
So if you want to make the `Player1` score 1, you need to provide it with the updated dict:

```
new_score = {'Player1': 1}
points.update(new_score)
```

Answer (score 0):

To access dictionary elements, you can use the familiar square brackets along with the key to obtain its value. 
for ex:

```
>>>points={'player1':0, 'player2':0}
>>>points['player1']
0
```

If you want to increment or decrement element by 1 you could use something like this

```
points['player1'] +=1   (increment the value of player1 by 1)
points['player2'] -=1   (decrement the value of player2 by 1)
```

Or using `get()` method

```
# Increment value in dictionary 
points['player1'] = points.get('player1', 0) + num
```